# p-value and confidence interval of hazard ratio disagree - why?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value, survival

In survival analysis, sometimes the p-value < 0.05 but the 95% confidence interval of the hazard ratio covers 1.0. In this case, we would choose to believe the confidence interval more than the p-value.

What could be the reason leading to p<0.05 but hazard ratio 95% confidence interval covers 1.0?

Comment: Can you show the output of the software or the publication? Also, what methods were used to calculate the p-value and the confidence interval? What was the null hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, what is estimated is the log hazard ratio instead of the hazard ratio directly. This is than transformed to hazard ratios. One typically computes the standard error and test statistics with the Delta method, which is an approximation. For the confidence interval there are multiple approximations, some are guaranteed to match with the delta method, but others, with better coverage properties, can differ. In practice the disagreement happens when the p-value is close to the critical value. So we wouldn't be able to distinguish between significant and nonsignificant anyhow.